# Word describing sitting on a couch comfortably

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you say someone is sitting on a couch in a very comfortable and lazy way? It's not exactly lying down, but sitting in a relaxed way. Is there a verb describing it?

Comment: "Lounge" comes to mind, as in _chaise lounge_.

Comment: @Cascabel There's no such thing.  It's a *chaise lonGUE*.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaise_longue

Comment: In New York they were called [chaise lounge](https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/sb0/chaise-lounge-chairs-c413911.html), and also [here](https://www.overstock.com/Home-Garden/Living-Room-Chairs/Chaise-Lounges,/chair-type,/2737/subcat.html)  Your own wiki article also states that in the US it is nearly always written _lounge_. @DavidM

Comment: @Cascabel I know. I'm from New York. I was being pedantic. 

Answer (score 6):

## Lounge

> : To lie, sit or lean in a relaxed or lazy way.

([From Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/lounge))

Therefore -

> "*She was **lounging** on the couch.*"

## Sprawl

> : To sit or lie with your arms and legs stretched out in different directions in a relaxed or careless way.

([From Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-sit-or-lie-down))

Therefore -

> "*The kids **sprawled** on the couch to watch TV.*"

Comment: For some perfect recent examples (with photos) of the term "lounging", refer to the articles about the British MP, Jacob Rees-Mogg, criticised for "lounging", "reclining" and "slouching" across the seats in the UK parliament in early Sep 2019 - e.g. https://www.newstatesman.com/politics/uk/2019/09/why-it-matters-jacob-rees-mogg-was-reclining-house-commons.

Comment: "Slouch" is another similar term - e.g. "He slouched across the couch, eyes half closed."

Comment: @TechnoCat - Yes, *slouch* seems good. You should add an answer.

Comment: Thank you @Justin, I appreciate your comment, but I think "lounge" is the best of all to convey the meaning the OP asked for, so I'm leaving this one for you! :)

Answer (score 2):

**recline on**

: to lie in a recumbent position — *usually used with on*

> on a sofa with two cylindrical pillows reclined a … pretty woman —
>   Thomas Hardy

Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged

Comment: Other examples: "He reclined, smiling, and accepted my offer to stay for a drink."

Answer (score 1):

**laid back** [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/105124?rskey=FJf0JW&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid39898643)

> Also, laid-back, inclined backwards; as figurative, relaxed.

Here, a phrase can be used literally and figuratively in the same sentence, reclined and relaxed.